I can't create a database entry using prisma
These are my models in prisma
model Task {
  id           String     @id @default(cuid())
  userId       String     @map("user_id")
  taskGroupId  String?    @default("") @map("task_group_id")
  name         String?
  content      String?
  isCompleted  Boolean?   @default(false) @map("is_completed")
  deadlines    DateTime?
  createdAt    DateTime   @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt    DateTime   @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  user         User       @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  taskGroup    TaskGroup? @relation(fields: [taskGroupId], references: [id])

  @@map("task")
}

model TaskGroup {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  userId    String   @map("user_id")
  name      String?
  color     String?
  createdAt DateTime @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  user      User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  task      Task[]

  @@map("task_group")
}

This is my task creation function:
  async create(dto: TaskDto, userId: string) {
    const { taskGroupId,...taskData } = dto;

    return this.prisma.task.create({
      data: {
        user: {
          connect: {
            id: userId,
          },
        },
        taskGroup: taskGroupId? {
          connect: {
            id: taskGroupId,
          },
        } : undefined,
      },
    });
  }

Foreign key constraint failed on the field: `task_task_group_id_fkey (index)`

I get this error if I send an empty object in a request to create a task.
I don’t understand how I can create a task without being linked to a task group.
